# How To Add,Update And Delete From Json DataType On Postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, sqldatatypes

This is my table on PostgreSQL with name contacts:
[image]

1. I want to edit mobile1 value with this sql query:

`update contacts->info set mobile1 = JSON_SET(mobile1, "123456") where id=5`

but that says :: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "->"

2. and when i want to delete or add a value with this sql query:

`delete orders->info->mobile2 where id=5`

syntax error at or near "orders"

3. Or ADD

`update orders->info set mobile3 = JSON_SET(mobile3, "123456") where id=5`

syntax error at or near "->"

**What's my syntax problem? and how can I do add, update and delete on my json datatype table on PostgreSQL**

Comment: Unrelated but this would be _much_ better and easier with a normalized data design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html) for insert, update, or delete you should use `JSONB` operation or function.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c39f692a31d32a3233852a40ff283cf8)

1. Update scenario:

```sql
update contacts
set info = jsonb_set(info::jsonb, '{mobile,mobile1}', '"123456"')::json
where id = 5;
```

2. Delete scenario:

```sql
update contacts
set info = (info::jsonb #- '{mobile,mobile2}')::json
where id = 5;
```

2. Add scenario:

```sql
update contacts
set info = jsonb_set(info::jsonb, '{mobile,mobile3}', '"123456"')::json
where id = 5;
```

Comment: thanks all of above worked, how can i add multiple mobile numbers on 1 query , add mobile4,mobile5,mobile6 ?

Comment: You can use https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8f4bafda9482847fa0fe0939ae51efe1 if needed add multiple keys

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for your question 1.**

Updating the `mobile1` json value in the `info` json field :

```
   update contacts 
      set info = jsonb_set(info :: jsonb, '{mobile,mobile1}', '123456', true) :: json
    where id=5
```

**Solution for your question 2.**

Removing the `mobile2` key/value pair from the `info` json field :

```
   update contacts 
      set info = (info :: jsonb #- '{mobile,mobile2}') :: json
    where id=5
```

Deleting the entire row from the contacts table :

```
delete from contacts where id=5
```

You should read carefully the manual [Chapter 6. Data Manipulation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/dml.html) and [9.16. JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html)

Comment: thanks, your solution for question 1 this error appeard : ```ERROR:  column "123456" does not exist```
for question 2 that worked@ 
and for question 3 how can I add another on my mobiles for example mobile3=987456 ?

Comment: Yes indeed I copied / pasted your piece of code with double quotes instead of simple quotes. I've updated my answer.